# How can we upload only files of a certain type when uploading a folder to Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive

I have a large number of `.cpp` (C++) files I would like to upload to Google Drive. However, on my computer, the C++ programs are stored with their compilation as well, and the compilation tends to be much larger than the C++ programs. However, my aim is just to backup my existing `.cpp` files, so I do not need to also upload the compiled files as well.

So overall, my question is: Is there any way to specify files types for Google Drive to accept or ignore, when uploading a folder to Google Drive?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. How are you uploading the files to Google Drive? Are you using the web app or the desktop app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in Ubuntu, you can use the terminal, or if you are in windows, you can use the Git Bash to separate the C++ files.

1. Go to the folder containing the C++ files, right click and open terminal / Git Bash.
2. First, make a new folder using the command: `mkdir only_cpp_files`
3. Then copy the files with the extension .cpp to the only_cpp_files using the command: `cp *.cpp only_cpp_files/` 
   Now you can upload only_cpp_files folder to Google Drive.